# How to force php to unsupress errors

Tags: php, error-reporting

I am using a large 3rd-party php software, which has a number of bugs I am trying to fix. However, this is very difficult to do, because it has a lot of error supression using @ - e.g. `@include 'brokenfile.php';`, which causes php to die without displaying any kind of error. So all I'm seeing is a blank screen, which tells me nothing. How do I force php to show errors, despite them being 'supressed'?

Comment: Just enable scream extension and use ini_set('scream.enabled', true)

Answer (score 5):

There is an extension called [`scream`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.scream.php) it will disable the `@` operator for debugging

From the manual:

> The scream extension gives the possibility to disable the silencing error control operator so all errors are being reported. This feature is controlled by an ini setting.

Install the extension and then enable it in your php.ini:

```
scream.enabled = On
```

---

Alternative:

This functionality is available with the recent xdebug version as well. You'll need xdebug installed and set

```
xdebug.scream = On
```

in php.ini

Comment: Scream would be perfect, but it doesn't work for me. phpinfo says it is enabled, but @ is still preventing errors.

Comment: You'll have to install the extension first. The manual contains information about how to do this

Comment: It seems it's time to update xdebug and remove scream. Thanks for the share.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to remove all "@" from your code recursively using small shell command:

```
find . -type f | xargs perl -pi -e 's/^@|(\s)@/$1/g'
```

or you can create backups for each updated files:

```
find . -type f | xargs perl -pi.bkp -e 's/^@|(\s)@/$1/g'
```

Comment: And how will you apply them again? While it is funny to suggest a perl solution it will cause serious damage in the code

Comment: @hek2mgl true, but that's only if a versioning system (e.g. git, svn, etc) is not used - you could do this, debug the problem, and then revert the files before performing the fix.

Comment: @hek2mgl If you don't use versioning system it's possible to create backup files:

    perl -e "s/FIND/REPLACE/g;" -pi.bkp $(find path/app -type f)

Comment: @Benubird yeah, the first thing to do is to add code to repository.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<?php

function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline )
{
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}

set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

function catchException($e)
{
    if (error_reporting() === 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Do some stuff
}

set_exception_handler('catchException');

?>
```

"If you have set a custom error handler function with set_error_handler() then it will still get called, but this custom error handler can (and should) call error_reporting() which will return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an @."

Ref : [Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0):

**Quick & dirty, hacky solution:** You could do a find & replace for the entire project and simply delete all @ that have an empty space before them, in Netbeans this is possible with `Ctrl+H`. The pattern you are searching for would be " @" (empty space and at-character).